# DynamoDB table design to query all items of a many to many schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We use aws DynamoDB. Our model consists of `groups` and `elements` that are in a many-to-many relation.

We follow the single table design pattern and designed our DynamoDb table as following:

|  | partitionKey | sortKey | attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | urn:nid:group:1 | urn:nid:group:1 | values group 1 |
| x | urn:nid:group:2 | urn:nid:group:2 | values group 2 |
|  | urn:nid:element:1 | urn:nid:element:1 | values element 1 |
|  | urn:nid:element:2 | urn:nid:element:2 | values element 2 |
|  | urn:nid:element:3 | urn:nid:element:3 | values element 3 |
| x | urn:nid:group:1 | urn:nid:element:1 | sortOrder |
| x | urn:nid:group:1 | urn:nid:element:2 | sortOrder |
| x | urn:nid:group:2 | urn:nid:element:1 | sortOrder |
| x | urn:nid:group:2 | urn:nid:element:3 | sortOrder |

How can we fetch all items marked with "x", namely all groups including their element relations? How do we have to modify our table layout to fetch these rows using a query and not a scan?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a GSI with PK defined as `explanation` and SK defined as `partitionKey`.  Then you can query this GSI with `PK = "relation"`, which will get you a list of all elements sorted by `group:#` without a need to do a `scan`.

Comment: explanation is not part of my current model, i added that column to the question to explain the model. I just edited my question. So your advise is to add a field for "type" and use that as PK in a GIS, right?

Comment: Yes, if you can come up with a GSI partition key that will allow you to differentiate a "relation" record from a "group" or an "element" one, this will allow you to query that partition instead of scanning the entire table.